# PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode

Tags: docker, pm2

I tried to use docker to run `graphql` server in no daemon mode, but was getting bellow error:

```
docker run graphql-server

2020-01-29T22:08:31: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2020-01-29T22:08:31: PM2 error: Script not found: /usr/src/app/run
2020-01-29T22:08:31: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
```

Here are the files i was using:

The Dockerfile

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .env ./
RUN apk add --no-cache curl && npm install --production
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV production
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "run", "dev", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
    apps : [{
      name: 'graphql-server',
      script: './index.js',
  
      autorestart: true,
  
      env: {
      },
      env_production: {
      }
    }],
  };
```

package.json

```
"scripts": { 
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js --ext js --exec babel-node",
    "lint": "standard",
    "lint:fix": "standard --fix"
  }
```

What's the reason i was having this error?

Comment: Hi Jorge, welcome to Stack Overflow!

You have to ask a question, and describe your steps a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows ? 
If you are, what is your windows docker desktop version ?
I am using windows and my windows docker desktop version is 2.2.0.3 .
And I have almost the same DockerFile as your, and I have the same problem.
After I Changed to use ubuntu 16.04 /18.04, it worked.
At now trying to windows docker desktop  2.1.0.5 ...